# Metric Space non-negative

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A common proof of the non-negativity of a distance in a metric space is the following (I found one like this on Wikipedia):

$d(x,y)+d(y,x) ≥ d(x,x)$

$d(x,y)+d(x,y) ≥ 0$

$2d(x,y) ≥ 0$

$d(x,y) ≥ 0$

However, the very first step seems to assume non-negativity. If we don't assume non-negativity then it is possible that

$d(x,y)+d(y,x) < 0$

It seems wrong that we assume the conclusion in the first step of the proof...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what this question is about? You should prove non-negativity from other conditions  of  a metric and not start assuming non-negativity as the approved answer does.

Answer (score 2):

The first step is triangle in equality. [Put $z=x$ in $d(z,x) \leq d(z,y)+d(y,x)$ ]. If you assume that all properties of a metric except non-negativity are satisfied then  this proof does show that $d(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$.

The second step uses the fact that $d(x,x)=0$. The third one uses symmetry: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.

Comment: The triangle equality, as I understand it, assumes the values are positive distances in Euclidean space. So wouldn't using the triangle inequality be an assumption of non-negativity?

Comment: This question is not based standard definition of  a metric. It is an abstract questioin where you have to assume only what you are asked to assume and not bring any intuition etc.  @NickyDoesThings

Answer (score 0):

It just depends *how* you define a metric on a set $M$.  Here's one with only two axioms:

Let $d\colon M^2\to \mathbb R$ satisfy the "goat's axiom":

For all $x,y,z\in M$ we have $$d(x,z)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,y).$$
(Imagine $z$ is a peg where two goats $x$ and $y$ are tied up with rows of length $d(x,z)$ and $d(y,z)$, resp.  Then their distance is at most $d(x,z)+d(y,z)$.)

The second axiom the symmetry of $d$:
$$d(x,y)=d(y,x).$$
 Then $d$ must be non-negative: from the goat's axiom we have
$$d(x,z)\geq d(x,y)-d(y,z).$$
Now let $z=x$ and use symmetry.

The triangle inequality also follows easily.

Answer (score -1):

The distance in a space $X$ is, by definition, a function $d:X \mathrm{x} X\to\mathbb{R}^+$. So the non-negativity of $d$ is given in the definition itself.

Comment: You can assume that $d$ takes nonnegative values and it is often done, but as Kavi Rama Murthy's answer shows, this is follows automatically from the other defining properties.

Comment: The whole purpose of the argument given in the question is to omit non-negativity from the definition and prove it as  a consequence.